# How to merge two recorded games in AoE2 DE that share a common point?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-de

Situation: We were playing a game and the game dropped. Then we restored the game. Now I have two recorded game: one before the drop and one after the restore.

Question: How can I merge these two records into one record?

Use-case: Actually I have many such recorded games that I have just manually renamed as part-1, part-2, part-3 etc... But in the end it becomes difficult to mannage. I wish I could merge them for some sanity.

p.s.: I found a great github repository [aoe2recfun](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/aoe2recfun) that merges "replays from different players together so that you can see all the chats in one replay". I have asked this question as [a feature request on its github issues.](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/aoe2recfun/issues/1)

I also asked this question on [Reddit AoE2](https://www.reddit.com/r/aoe2/comments/w17c9q/how_to_merge_two_recorded_games_in_aoe2_de_that/).

Prompted by [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/aoe2/comments/w17c9q/comment/igitjhj/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) I discovered another great github repository [aoc-mgz](https://github.com/happyleavesaoc/aoc-mgz). I have asked this question on [its github issues](https://github.com/happyleavesaoc/aoc-mgz/issues/86) as well.